# How to add lightbox in a single html file?

Tags: javascript, html, css, lightbox

I tried lightbox out and everything works fine with it on my home pc.
But now, I wonder if it's possible to add lightbox in a single html file.
I used three different folders for it (css, js, html).

But now I want to add it only in the html file.
For css I can put the code in 
For js I can add it in  normaly, but this doesn't work for me.

The js code is from the lightbox site:

```js
"(function (root, factory) {
    if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
        // AMD. Register as an anonymous module.
        define(['jquery'], factory); .......... etc"
```

I want to run it online and have only space for an one pager (so I can't add separate folders like css and js, that's why I have to put everthing in one html folder).

Comment: your code has syntax errors, also why is the function in a double quotes ? `"`

Answer (score 1):

Add it in a `<script>` tag:

```
<script>
  /* lightbox code from file here */
</script>
```

Depending on the lightbox execution you may want to put it in the document `<head>` or just above the close `</body>` tag.